# C++: Possible to work with internal DLL naming?

Tags: c++, dll

I have some DLLs of similar types and one or more can be loaded at runtime. E.g., foo1.dll", "foo2.dll", "bar1.dll". They all belong to the category of DLLs "baz". I'd like to give them internal name strings within each DLL, like "baz:foo1", "baz:foo2", and "baz:bar1" and have my executable query all loaded DLLs to find those whose names contain the substring "baz".

Is this possible? If so, which functions calls facilitate a list of loaded DLL names? Sorry for the basic question, but I searched online and got swamped with unrelated hits. I'm working with VS on Windows.

Comment: Add a function to each DLL that return its name.

Comment: @RichardCritten, thanks. How then would I iterate through all loaded DLLs to query which had a function to return a name?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I may be missing something, but I came across that example and coded it before posting and it returned a list of system processes, not the DLLs that my executable linked to.

Comment: There is no difference between a system dll and a dll you have loaded yourself.